# geo_point in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to map a latitude and longitude to a geo_point in Elastic.

Here's my log file entry:

```
13-01-2017 ORDER COMPLETE: £22.00 Glasgow, 55.856299, -4.258845
```

And here's my conf file

```
input {
file {
  path => "/opt/logs/orders.log"
  start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter {
   grok {
       match => { "message" => "(?<date>[0-9-]+) (?<order_status>ORDER [a-zA-Z]+): (?<order_amount>£[0-9.]+) (?<order_location>[a-zA-Z ]+)"}
}

mutate {
       convert => { "order_amount" => "float" }
       convert => { "order_lat" => "float" }
       convert => { "order_long" => "float" }

       rename => {
                  "order_long" => "[location][lon]"
                  "order_lat" => "[location][lat]"
       }
 }
}

output {
      elasticsearch {
               hosts => "localhost"

               index => "sales"
               document_type => "order"

     }
    stdout {}
}
```

I start logstash with `/bin/logstash -f orders.conf` and this gives:

```
"@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true,
"properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"},
"location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"},
"longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
```

See? It's seeing `location` as a geo_point. Yet `GET sales/_mapping` results in this:

```
"location": {
        "properties": {
          "lat": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "lon": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

### Update

Each time I reindex, I stop logstash thenremove the .sincedb from `/opt/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file...`. I have also made a brand new log file and I increment the index each time (I'm currently up to `sales7`).

**conf file**

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/opt/ag-created/logs/orders2.log"
     start_position => "beginning"
   }
}

filter {
  grok {
     match => { "message" => "(?<date>[0-9-]+) (?<order_status>ORDER [a-zA-Z]+): (?<order_amount>£[0-9.]+) (?<order_location>[a-zA-Z ]+), (?<order_lat>[0-9.]+), (?<order_long>[-0-9.]+)( - (?<order_failure_reason>[A-Za-z :]+))?" }
}

 mutate {
    convert => { "order_amount" => "float" }
 }

 mutate {
    convert => { "order_lat" => "float" }
 }

 mutate {
    convert => { "order_long" => "float" }
 }

 mutate {
     rename => { "order_long" => "[location][lon]" }
 }

 mutate {
     rename => { "order_lat" => "[location][lat]" }
  }
 }

output {
      elasticsearch {
               hosts => "localhost"
               index => "sales7"
               document_type => "order"
               template_name => "myindex"
               template => "/tmp/templates/custom-orders2.json"
               template_overwrite => true
     }

    stdout {}
}
```

**JSON file**

```
 {
  "template": "sales7",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
 },
"mappings": {
"sales": {
  "_source": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
  }
        index => "sales7"
               document_type => "order"
               template_name => "myindex"
               template => "/tmp/templates/custom-orders.json"
               template_overwrite => true
     }

    stdout {}
}
```

Interestingly, when the `geo_point` mapping doesn't work (ie. both lat and long are floats), my data is indexed (30 rows). But when the `location` is correctly made into a `geo_point`, none of my rows are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to do this. First one is creating a template for your mapping to create a correct mapping while indexing you data. Because Elasticseach does not understand what your data type is. You should say it theses things like below.

Firstly, create a template.json file for your mapping structure:

```
{
  "template": "sales*",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "sales": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
}
```

After that change your logstash configuration to put this mapping your index :

```
input {
file {
  path => "/opt/logs/orders.log"
  start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter {
   grok {
       match => { "message" => "(?<date>[0-9-]+) (?<order_status>ORDER [a-zA-Z]+): (?<order_amount>£[0-9.]+) (?<order_location>[a-zA-Z ]+)"}
}

mutate {
       convert => { "order_amount" => "float" }
       convert => { "order_lat" => "float" }
       convert => { "order_long" => "float" }

       rename => {
                  "order_long" => "[location][lon]"
                  "order_lat" => "[location][lat]"
       }
 }
}

output {
      elasticsearch {
                hosts => "localhost"

                index => "sales"
                document_type => "order"
                template_name => "myindex"
                template => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/template.json"
                template_overwrite => true


     }
    stdout {}
}
```

Second option is ingest node feature. I will update my answer for this option but now you can check [my dockerized repository](https://github.com/hkulekci/es5-devnot/blob/master/.docker/logstash/conf/logstash.conf). At this example, I used ingest node feature instead of template while parsing location data.

Comment: Thanks. This is strange because I'm now seeing the structure as a geopoint but it doesn't index any data. `GET sales5/_count` (with both long and lat as floats) shows `30` indexed documents. `GET sales6/_count` (with the `location` correctly picked up as a geo_point shows `0` documents. I'm deleting the sincedb each time and (as you can see, incrementing the index and altering both the JSON and conf files

Comment: if you are using `dynamic:strict` of mapping, this can be. Other wise, please check the logstash responses on the console. It will be give information about indexing errors.

Comment: I've turned on debugging `--debug` and I'm now getting `glob is []`. I've recreated the log file and it still doesn't index properly. Getting closer to calling it a bug...

Comment: To solve problem, could you give an example file and I will try to index this file to an Elasticsearch and I try to create a dockerized repository.

Comment: ahh I found solution you dont need send lat long seperated as array send these data with comma seperated.